# Li Ion computer battery puncture

Tags: batteries

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I accidentally punctured just the very first (pouch?) layer on my MacBook lithium ion battery. A smell came out of it but the battery still works fine and holds charge. from what I've read, this is just the solvent being released from the battery and I haven't actually damaged the battery cell itself. But I can't find the answer to is this in danger of exploding? Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQZ4p.jpg)[image]

Comment: Yes.  Pics or it didn't happen.  You either damaged an outer layer of additional casing, which is unlikely if something with a smell was released or you created a hole that you simply can't see in the actual cell.  If the latter is the case, it hasn't exploded *yet*.  Charging the cell could cause it to "go off" if this is the case, and if allowed to deplete itself the cell will be less dangerous.  Metal containers and a suitable storage locations are your friends while you figure it out.

Comment: If you had a hot fire the size of a softball/basketball burning unattended and you wanted it to store it so as to expend its fuel without damaging anything else, this is the way you should store the battery.  Note that aluminum melts at only 660\$^\circ\$C so only very thick aluminum containers are suitable.

Comment: Prop up the battery and hold the camera still and think about angle of lighting to get a better picture.  That one isn't good enough.

Comment: Aiming at something at an equal depth from the lens will help you get the camera to focus on a thin object.  It appears to have focused on the consumer label in the background.

Comment: The silver part is not damaged at all it is just the black material surrounding the inside that is damaged

Comment: What does it smell like?

Comment: closest thing I can describe to it is a sweet smelling nail polish remover or like a sweeter version of paint thinner

Comment: That is the smell of solvent of a compromised pack. You might argue it's residual from manufacture...but that's chancing it.

Comment: I wound not go anywhere near that thing! Place it outside in a fireproof bucket with a lid on it.

Comment: From personal experience there's no such thing as residual smells on a lithium cell: if you smell that nail polish type smell: your cell is compromised. **Dispose of it immediately!** (securely. That means definitely not the trash bin.)

Comment: alright battery is out of my laptop, how exactly do i sfley dispose of it, scared of it even being in my house. I don't have a fireproof bucket

Comment: If you have a steel trash can or ammo box that would do it. Just keep a cracked lid on it. You want not only want to contain any fireballs but be able to vent any gasses/pressure. Sealing it in just makes it more like a bomb. A sand-filled bucket works if you have no steel containers. Ultimately, you take it to your eco-centre.

Comment: Ideally you would discharge it first...somehow (IMO that's the tricky part). Some people say salt water baths but those are of questionable effectiveness and some say it makes it worse by corroding the contacts and other methods have their own hazards. Most casual users of lithium batteries aren't equipped or knowledgable enough to to do that anyways.

Comment: @DKNguyen Questionable indeed, given lithium self combusts in water. xD Don't ever use water with a punctured lithium battery. It'll help prevent too much heat if it's already on fire, but it might ignite it altogether if it's not.

Answer (score 4):

It's damaged. The solvent is part of the electrolyte in the battery.

Keep it outside in a vented firesafe area until you can dispose of it properly. The last time I punctured a lithium battery it ignited a blue flame that luckily extinguished itself while I was running to toss it outside which is where it stayed thereafter. But they have been known to explode into a fireball and burn things down when punctured.

Comment: So even if I didn't damage the inside of the battery its still dangerous? I did not puncture the actual cell. It was just the coating on the outside of the battery

Comment: if you can smell it, sell it.

Comment: @hawkeyes17 You described it as a solvent that smells which could only be the electrolyte normally INSIDE the cell. If it is, you did puncture the cell. I don't know how you could think you did not puncture the cell when liquid is leaking out of it. Where did you even read the it is okay?

Comment: Theres no liquid coming out of it.

Comment: @hawkeyes17 You're contradicting yourself.  You can smell it, which means something is coming out somewhere.

Comment: you're right. let me rephrase what I originally said. Theres no liquid coming out of the battery. The battery still works completely fine, charges and discharges as normal. The only not normal thing is the smell that is coming from the battery.

Comment: @hawkeyes17  Post photos. If you don't recognize the smell, it is probably not adhesive, and is also fresh (which adhesive would not be). That leaves electrolyte.

Comment: added photo now

Comment: @hawkeyes17 Take it from a couple more angles. It's difficult to figure out perspective when we are not there. Use a light or flash to see inside if you can